# How to set connectionstring at web.config file programmatically or dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET website. There I'm using a database. To connect with the database I'm using the connectionstring which I've stored in the web.config file like

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DBConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=G:\CarRentalServices\App_Data\CarRentalServiceDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

and at code behind

```
private string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

So you can see the database is stored at `G:\path\to\db\CarRentalServiceDB.mdf`.

But now if my friend want to take the project from me and try to run the project from his machine then he has to change the `connectionString` at `web.config`. Say the website is now at `D:\path\to\db\foo\CarRentalServiceDB.mdf` in my friend's machine, then the connectionString needs to change. Isn't it tedious?

Is there any way to change the `connectionString` dynamically with any batch file or code so that it will change with respect to the current directory it is residing now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud use the |DataDirectory| token: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="DBConnectionString" 
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\CarRentalServiceDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Comment: Tried this but getting a SqlException. I deleted the log file also as described in the link. Any other solution?

Comment: What is the Exception details? Where is the data file stored?

Comment: Solved. used the connection-string as `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CarRentalServiceDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You would add multiple connections strings in your web.config file and call the one you need like

**Web.config File**

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DBConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=G:\CarRentalServices\App_Data\CarRentalServiceDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
  <add name="DBConnectionStringTwo" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\path\to\db\foo\CarRentalServiceDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Code for connection strings**

```
//Connection String 1 
private string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

//Connection String 2 
private string _connectionString2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionStringTwo"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Yes this can be one thing, but can there be any batch file or code will be triggered when the solution is build, then the `web.config` will be updated with the database path for `AttachDbFilename`?